# Accidentally uninstalled mysql on AWS EC2 with wordpress multisite. Need a little guidance

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a wordpress multisite installation running on an AWS EC2 (t2.medium).

After messing around trying to get phpmyadmin installed on the server I accidentally deleted httpd,mysql-server etc. It broke everything.

Thankfully, I used a plugin called Snapshot from wpmu-dev and had everything backed up but now I'm running into some trouble and not entirely sure how to do this.

Current situation: 
1. Created an instance snapshot through my aws dashboard.
2. Backed up everything from /var/www/html/ to my local drive. 
3. Reinstalled mysql and httpd, started it, went through the steps provided here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html - however, when setting up the database it states that wordpress-db and the user are already there and my old password still works yet wordpress isn't working?

So I'm not sure where to go from here, shall I just delete my instance and start again from scratch? Loading what I need back into the /var/www/html folder? Or is there a way that I can completely delete my database and then rebuild the tables with the snapshot and get back to where I started?

Thanks in advance for your help folks, really stuck here, have a website that's down!

Comment: Do you have a Snapshot of the instance in AWS? You can restore one of those to get everything back.

Comment: I don't... kicking myself! Only the backup through the snapshot plugin in wordpress (I know it has all the database tables, though). Just to figure out how to get everything back on.

Comment: what di you mean by `wordpress isn't working` . is your word press site does not show anything or error or what you get when you visit?

Comment: @webDev I deleted mysql by mistake, reinstalled it, but now my address isn't working. Just showing the apache test page.

Comment: i think problem with your files, directory and permissions may be... because you are not getting any database error right?

Comment: @webDev It appears the tables have been deleted, since wordpress is no longer showing up but the database and the users in mysql are still there after I reinstalled it.

Comment: yeah if database problem then you should get error when you visit the page. did you enable your error reporting of php. Because if you put your wordpress website file in right place and configured with right db there must be some error when you visit the page. Its does not matter whether the table is there or not, first try to visit the page and get error msg. how you know the problem is DB, if DB problem you will get error msg

Comment: @webDev it only happened after I deleted mysql-server, so I presume it's a problem with the database. Nothing else was changed. I've made a backup of everything and going to see if I can rebuild the tables of the database with a fresh wordpress install then migrate all my files back over. Unless you have another suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure what happened I would recommend you start from scratch.

1. Launch an EC2 instance and follow the steps on the guide you provided:
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html
2. Download MySQL workbench and connect to the database (remember
   modifying the security permissions temporarily
   to be able to connect to the database from your computer) (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)
3. Restore the sql backup (if you have one, or create one if you don't) to restore the database to your new ec2 instance MySQL. You can do this following the Data import section: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html
4. Make sure the configuration file is correct (url, database path, name, etc) (https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)
5. I would recommend to point your domain to your new ec2 instance only after it has been properly configured and tested.